# How to remove only one occurrence of a key in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, del

Suppose I have

```
hand={"a":"2","p":"3","l":"1","e":"1","a":"13"}
```

if i use `del["a"]` it removes all the occurrences, but how to delete only one occurrence?

Comment: `{"a":"2","p":"3","l":"1","e":"1","a":"13"}` does not have 2 occurences of the key `a` in the first place, dictionary keys must be unique. see the result of `print(hand)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. but how to delete the first a only? If that's what i want to achieve?

Comment: **There is no first or second `a`**. A dictionary can always only have **one** instance of a key. Please read up on what dictionaries are.

Comment: In this dictionary of yours, what is the result of hand['a']?

Comment: what does `print hand` show (without removing any `'a'` keys?)

Answer (score 2):

There's no two occurences of any key in a dictionary. That's not how dictionaries work: Any key can only exist ONE time in a dictionary.

So `del` will remove the single occurrence of `"a"`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @vishu is talking about nested dictionaries.

Comment: @waqasgard look at the comments under his question: he's not. alos, this was actually three years ago...

Answer (score 0):

`Dict` in python does not support duplicate keys. Just imagine you need to access a particular value using a key. How would you access it if there were two values associated to the key in question?

You can store a list against the key. Like `{'a': [1, 2]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually store multiple keys of the same type in Python so… sorry.